# Rename remote + repo foral

Tags: git, repo

I have renamed remotes using the command:

```
repo forall -c "git remote rename A B"
```

Two pieces were renamed well

But now, I get

```
Got an error, terminating the pool: 
GitError: None: remote A does not have refs/heads/A
```

`repo forall -c "git remote -v"` shows not all remotes, but only before the error.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `repo forall -c "git branch -avv"` if you see branches and remote tracking branching (the `B/<branchName>`) with `A/...` instead of `B/...`.

And do a `repo forall -c "git fetch"` to force the creation of `B/<branchName>` remote tracking branches.

Answer (score 0):

Everything turned out to be simple.

I used

```
Repo sync
```